# How To Make df wider with multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to figure out a quick way to pivot this table. My input table is like this

```
+------+------+------+
| FY   | col1 | col2 |
+------+------+------+
| 2019 | 34   | 28   |
+------+------+------+
| 2018 | 22   | 39   |
+------+------+------+
```

and I want my output table to be

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| col1.2018 | col1.2019 | col2.2018 | col2.2018 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 22        | 34        | 39        | 28        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What is the most quick way to do it? I tries using reshape and tidyr but I am not getting the output desired. Any guidance or direction is appreciated

Edit: This is not an exact duplication of other question as pointed out. Although its similar, but not same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An option would be to `gather` the columns ('col1', 'col2') to long format with `gather`), `unite` the 'key' with 'FY' column and then `spread` back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, col1:col2) %>%
     unite(key1, key, FY, sep=".") %>%
     spread(key1, val)
#   col1.2018 col1.2019 col2.2018 col2.2019
#1        22        34        39        28
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(FY = c(2019, 2018), col1 = c(34, 22), col2 = c(28, 
 39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: superquick.. good lord thank you so much.. I will accept your solution in next 8 mins.. :)